# PhpStorm Setting Repository token

Tags: github, repository, phpstorm, token, settings

I have configured PhpStorm to use GitHub repository to save IDE settings. Everything seems to work but PhpStorm always ask for the GitHub token.

Is there a way to store it definitely?

Comment: Do you have issues with other passwords/tokens (e.g. FTP passwords/other GitHub reps etc)? IDE version? What OS you are on? What password storage is used?

Comment: Hi, I have this kind of problem only with Phpstorm 2017.3 Build 173.3727.138 on Debian Buster. How can I seet what password storage I'm using?

Comment: `File | Settings | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings | Passwords`. But I was not talking about other apps -- I'm talking about other areas inside PhpStorm. If it's keychain then your system may not have right components installed and your passwords are simply not saved/remembered. Switching to KeePass should solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks, I have find the section and in fact I had the "In native Keychain" setting

Comment: Switching to KeePass is the easiest way. If you want to keep using keychain -- please check your `idea.log` for possible hints. I'm not a Linux person .. but it might be this one: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-160703 (`sudo apt-get install gnome-keyring` may be needed). if not -- check for other tickets in that subsystem.

Comment: I think that "KeePass" it's ok. For now seems to work

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your passwords/tokens are not saved/remembered across IDE sessions.

If you are on Linux and using Keychain to tore passwords (check at `File | Settings | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings | Passwords`) then please switch to KeePass option -- this should resolve the issue.

If you want to keep using Keychain -- you may not have necessary components installed (if they are available for your environment) -- e.g. `sudo apt-get install gnome-keyring` might be needed.